# Changing appearence of dropped item in React DND

Tags: reactjs, react-dnd

Is there a way to modify item once dropped into Drop Target with React DND ? I have a basic Card with an image and text block. By default, the text is not shown (display: none).

I would be able to change this attribute so that once dropped, text block is shown in drop zone..

Can someone explains me how I can do that please?

I tried with endDrag function but it is the drag source which is modified, not the drag item itself...

Thanks.